ggplot geom_smooth() for linear regression dummy variable - no regression lines
I apologize in advance for my first question on this platform. I had browsed many threads, but most of the things I found do not involve any dummy variables.
However, after around 4 hours of investigating the issue, I cannot seem to figure out what's wrong.
For teaching and demonstration purposes, I am currently trying to setup a little plot of a dummy variable linear model using the well know iris dataset.
However, no matter what I try, I cannot get it to plot more than one regression line at once, whereas I would be expecting two: one from versicolor to setosa and one from virginica to setosa, with setosa being the first group of the factor.
Here's my code and what I have tried so far.
#Loading the tidyverse.
library(tidyverse)

#Loading the iris dataset and saving it as an object.
dataset <- as_tibble(iris)

#As a background: I'd like to visualize the following linear regression.
ols_lm_iris_all <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Species,
                      data = dataset)

summary(ols_lm_iris_all)

#This results in the following lm-model, which gives pairwise comparisons for: versicolor to setosa and virginica to setosa. So far so good.
#My code to visualize the data would be as follows.
iris_lm_plot_all <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Length, colour = Species)) +
                    geom_smooth(method = lm, aes(group = Species)) +
                    geom_jitter(width = 0.2) +
                    labs(title = "Linear OLS regression with two regression lines for three types of Iris.")

iris_lm_plot_all

#What I get in the end, however, is a scatter plot with jitter but without any regression lines at all.
#Here's what I've also tried, partly successfully. If we assign "aes(group = 1)" instead of group = Species, we get one lm-line from the last factor virginica to setosa. That is half the work, but now we don't get versicolor to setosa.
iris_lm_plot_all <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Length, colour = Species)) +
                    geom_smooth(method = lm, aes(group = 1)) +
                    geom_jitter(width = 0.2) +
                    labs(title = "Linear OLS regression with two regression lines for three types of Iris.")

What I also thought about: Could it be that geom_smooth does not handle the dummification of Species properly?

lm(Petal.Length ~ Species, data = {iris %>% filter(Species == "setosa")}) try this one to see why it cannot create a regression line for each species. Also, jitter is deceiving, use geom point instead to see how the data actually looks like.

Hi and thank you for your reply! I get what you mean with the jitter, but I actually enjoy it just to avoid some of the naturally overlap and to visualise all data points.
Ah, I think I see where you are going with your comment. You mean that the geom_smooth() code line fails because it cannot create a reg-line for every single group. That would indeed be true, because we only need two comparisons and hence only two lines.

What kind of regression line are you expecting when all the x values are the same for each group? It would make more sense to me if you were doing something like ggplot(dataset, aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Petal.Length, colour = Species)) + geom_smooth(method = lm, aes(group = Species)) + geom_point(width = 0.2)

Hi Jon!
The intention was to plot the pairwise-comparisons of the dummy variable. For three groups, we get two "dummified" regression lines that basically connect the means between the groups. The concept of dummies can be hard to grasp for students, so a plot like in the solution supplied by Miff (see below) can be helpful to show what's going on.

Also, I have to correct myself a little bit here.
By definition, we are not really conducting "complete" pair-wise comparisons. What we are actually doing is to compare all other groups to the first one. Just for clarification.
What's actually missing here is a comparison between level 2 and 3, versicolor and viriginica. But that is completely intentional.

The final plot isn't doing quite what you'd hoped. Species is being converted to a numeric, and then the lm is fitted to all three factors. It just happens in this example that it goes through the first and last cluster nicely, but if the factors are re-ordered that doesn't happen.
You can manually edit the data for two comparisons/three factors, but that doesn't easily generalise:
dataset <- as.tibble(iris)

dataset <- rbind(
  cbind(subset(dataset, as.numeric(Species) %in% c(1,2)),comparison="A"),
  cbind(subset(dataset, as.numeric(Species) %in% c(1,3)),comparison="B")
)

ggplot(dataset, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Length, colour = Species)) +
    geom_smooth(method = lm, aes(group=comparison)) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.2, ) +
  labs(title = "Linear OLS regression mit with two regression line for three types of Iris.")


This question has other approaches to plotting pairwise comparisons.

That's a pretty clear response! I really appreciate your solution. Also great that you debunked my previous idea of what I hoped whas happening.
I just wish there was a little more convenient way of doing this. I wonder if I'm the only one seeing a need for this or if my visualization idea is completely niche :)

I've also accepted your response as the solution. However, if somebody came up with a more convenient way, I'd still be interested of course.

A possible alternative formulation:
library(ggplot2)

iris |>  
  ggplot(aes(Species, Petal.Length, colour = Species, group = 1)) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, data = subset(iris, Species != "versicolor")) +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, data = subset(iris, Species != "virginica")) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.2) +
  labs(title = "Linear OLS regression with two regression line for three types of Iris.")


Created on 2024-04-15 with reprex v2.1.0

Hi Carl!
That is a very elegant solution, really appreciate your approach!
It seems to me that what we are basically doing is some kind of a manual "dummification" to direct geom_smooth to the exact comparisons. Don't have enough points yet to give you an upvote. Will do so after I've gotten some more.

Here's another approach to get a regression line for each combination of the Species instead of just two:
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

combn(group_split(iris, Species), 2, bind_rows, simplify = FALSE) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "ID") %>% 
  mutate(Species_Combn = paste(unique(Species), collapse = "-"), 
         .by = ID) -> iris_combn

suppressWarnings(
ggplot() +
  geom_smooth(data = iris_combn, method = lm, 
              aes(Species, Petal.Length, group = ID, colorL = Species_Combn)) +
  geom_jitter(data = iris, width = 0.2,
              aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Length, colorP = Species)) +
  scale_listed(
    list(scale_color_manual(values = c("blue4", "green4", "red4"), 
                           aesthetics = "colorL", name = "Species Combination"),
         scale_color_manual(values = c("blue3", "red3","green3"),
                           aesthetics = "colorP")),
    replaces = c("color", "color")) +
  labs(title = "Linear OLS regression for three types of Iris.")
)
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'


Created on 2024-04-16 with reprex v2.0.2

That's prety cool, too! Thanks for your contribution :)
